# generic code to compare 2 objects

Tags: c#, .net, comparison, data-annotations

i've two objects of different that need to be compared for equality

I can write some code using reflection to compare the property values but wondering if there're any new patterns in .net 4.0 that address this

Comment: the issue is what is equality? going beyond == the framework has no idea what kind of equality you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can write some code using reflection to compare the property values but wondering if there're any new patterns in .net 4.0 that address this

No. You'll have to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the common comparison properties in a common interface and simply compare them as that interface type.

Answer (score 0):

You need your class to implement `IComparable` and then override and implement the `CompareTo` method to help C# understand how it should compare those objects.

As an example, I want to compare two widgets. It is a complex class that contains both an integer and a string. I believe that the combination of the integer and the length of the string will determine which object is larger.

```
Class MyWidget : IComparable
{
    public int Piece { get; set; }
    public string Thing { get; set; }
    public MyWidget()
    {
        this.Piece = 1;
        this.Thing = "default";
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        var otherWidget = obj as MyWidget;
        if (otherWidget != null)
        {
            return (this.Piece + this.Thing.Length).CompareTo(otherWidget.Piece + otherWidget.Thing.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a MyWidget");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing objects you might want to redefine the **Equals()** function like this :

```
        public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        User testedUser = (User)obj;

        if (this._userName == testedUser.UserName &&
            this._userPassword == testedUser.UserPassword)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Then you can simply do a : userbob.Equals(userAnne)

Comment: Not quite so simple - if overriding Equals you should also override GetHashCode - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182358(v=vs.80).aspx.  And the properties used to determine equality should really be immutable.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick-and-dirty method of comparing large obejct graphs, dump each side to [json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and then use a [text diff](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13326/An-O-ND-Difference-Algorithm-for-C).